¿Cómo puedo detectar cuando se activa o desactiva un boton en C?
Quise crear un botón parecido al de un MessageBox, el cual cambia su estilo cuando es seleccionado y deseleccionado.
He estado buscando varias maneras para encontrar codigos de notifcacion de un botón de Winapi en C para detectar si un botón ha sido seleccionado o activado; simplemente dando un solo click en el mismo, sin tener que esperar hasta que suelte el click del ratón. Y tambien cuando ha sido deseleccionado o desactivado; cuando hacemos click fuera del area determinada del botón.
El mensaje WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN es parecido, ya que envia si se ha dado un click fuera de la ventana, pero eso lo obtiene solamente en el evento de la ventana principal y no del botón.
Ejemplo:
 #include <windows.h>

 LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
     switch(msg) 
     {
         case WM_CREATE: {
             //Crea un botón dentro de nuestra ventana principal
             CreateWindow("button","Button",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,15,15,75,22,hwnd,0,0,0);
         } break;
         
         case WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN: {
             /* Se envía cuando se hace un click fuera de la ventana portadora de este 
                procedimiento de ventana, en este caso la ventana principal */
         } break;

         case WM_COMMAND: {
             switch(HIWORD(wp)) 
             {
                 case BN_CLICKED: {
                     //Cuando soltamos el click en un botón dentro de la ventana
                 } brak;
             }
         } break;
         case WM_DESTROY: {
             PostQuitMessage(0);
             return 0;
         } break;
     }
     return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
 }

Esto lo que hace es detectar cuando soltamos el click en un boton, no cuando directamente hacemos el click.
Por el momento el evento afecta a todos los botones en general de la ventana, así que no hace falta especificar el identificador del boton.

No me queda claro cual es tu pregunta...

Quieres detectar cuando se presiona el clic izquierdo sobre el botón? La señal WM_COMMAND ocurre cuando el botón se suelta ya que es posible cancelar el clic moviendo el cursor de lugar antes de soltar el botón. Yo creo que deberías usar VM_LBUTTONDOWN o algún método alternativo.
